# Prepopulating custom field look up value on Opportunity Using URL hacking

Tags: urlhacking

There is master_account__c lookup(Account), Account(standard field) on Opportunity i am trying to prepopulate both the values with same Account field through custom button.I am able to prepouplate Account field  but failed to update  master_account__c lookup(Account).

Custom button code: 
/006/e?&accid={!Account.Id}

VF page for record type selection:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity"  extensions="OpportunityRecordTypeSelection">
   <apex:sectionHeader title="New Opportunity" subtitle="Select Opportunity Record Type"/>
        <apex:form id="theForm">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Select Opportunity Record Type">
                <apex:pageBlocksection >
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel > RecordType of new record </apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:selectList size="1"  value="{!selectedRecordType}"  >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordTypeList}" />
                        </apex:selectList> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 </apex:pageBlocksection>

                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">       
                    <apex:pageBlocksection >
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
                            <apex:commandButton action="{!continueToOpportunity}" value="Continue" />
                            <apex:commandButton onclick="CloseTab();return false;" action="{!cancelRec}" value="Cancel"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlocksection>
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons>   
               </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Apex controller:

```
public class OpportunityRecordTypeSelection
    {
        Opportunity a;
        ApexPages.StandardController controller;
         public Id accid;

        public OpportunityRecordTypeSelection(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
            a = (Opportunity) Controller.getRecord();
         accid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accid');

          }
public PageReference continueToOpportunity() 
        {   
            System.debug('@@@'+selectedRecordType);

            if((selectedRecordType =='PM-P Opportunity' || selectedRecordType =='FPD PR Opportunity' || selectedRecordType =='IR3535 EU' ||selectedRecordType )
            {

           Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(selectedRecordType).getRecordTypeId(); 

                if(accid!=Null)
                {
                PageReference pageRef=new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&accid='+accid+'&RecordType='+devRecordTypeId+'&ent=Opportunity&Master_Account__c='+accid+'&RecordType='+devRecordTypeId+'&ent=Opportunity');
                pageRef.getParameters().put('nooverride','1');
                pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;
                }
}
```

Please find the URL i am getting once i clicked on continue. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/) goes into detail on how to use urlhacking to prepopulate a custom lookup field.

> To populate a Lookup value we need the field ID as before but this
>   time we need to add CF to the front of the ID so it looks something
>   like this – CF00Ni000000EpsgO. This is required when populating a
>   custom lookup field.  The first part to populate a lookup value is to
>   grab the name of the record we are populating. So using the method
>   before but with the added CF you can expect your button URL to look
>   like this
>
> /a0U/e?CF00Ni000000EpsgO={!Opportunity.Name}
>
> The next step is to grab
>   the ID of the record we wish to populate. This time though, we are
>   going to add “_lkid” to the end of our field ID (plus the CF we added
>   on earlier). This lkid parameter is telling Salesforce this is a
>   lookup field. So it looks a bit like this.
>
> /a0U/e?CF00Ni000000EpsgO={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Ni000000EpsgO_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}

Comment: Thank you for your time @Todd Sprinkel. "/a0U/e?CF00Ni000000EpsgO={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Ni000000EpsgO_lkid={!Opportunity.Id} " This will work after New button. There will be Recordselection VF page after New button. In which i need to click on Continue button for the creation of Opportunity. I have given The controller and VF page code. How should i pass this lookup field in Pagerefernce method?